# Creating buttons from databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

this is propably an easy Problem, but I just can't wrap my head around it and hope that you can give me some advice.

My task is to write a small wpf application that loads a list of command-objects from a database and then dynamically adds a button to an wrappanel, binds the button to the loaded object and then executes the objects command if the button is clicked.

Is there any way to do this directly in XAML, or do I need to write C# code for the creation of the buttons and the data binding?

Thank you!

Comment: Use an ItemsControl with a WrapPanel as ItemsPanel. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: the way to do it in xaml is to use `ItemsControl` with WrapPanel as `ItemsPanel` and `ItemTemplate` with a button inside

Comment: The `ItemsSource` property of the ItemsControl would be bound to a collection of your command item objects. The `Command` property of the Button in the `ItemTemplate` would be bound to a property of type `ICommand` in the command item class.

Comment: Thank you all, ItemsControl solved my Problem.